# I'ld like to use phpstorm IDE as remote control for server

Tags: php, apache, phpstorm

I am doing as following:

```
    1) "create new project from existing sources"
    2) check at "webserver is on remote host, files are accessible via ftp/sftp/ftps"
    3) project name "myTest"
    4) add new remote server
    5) name: my-domain.com
    type: ftp
    ftp host: my-domain.de
    port: 21
    root path : / 
    username: my-username
    password: my-password

    window is popping up:
    "checking connection to my-domain.com"
    "connecting by ftp"
```

But everytime i am getting an error:

```
    "connection to 'my-domain.com' failed.
    HEAD method failed for "http://my-domain.com/" with HTTP status 403."
```

It is not wrong username and password, because i can login with these data via filezilla without having any trouble. Anyone with same Problem in past? Who knows how to handle that? Is there a further configuration at phpstorm needed to be able to use remote-control on server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Options were missing: at screen of 5) i clicked "Advanced options" and made a check at "compatibility mode" and "passive mode" (https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/advanced-options-dialog.html).
Additionally i made a check at "Don't check http connection" at screen 5).

Answer (score 1):

Are ftp and http server on similiar domain?

```
 HEAD method failed for "http://my-domain.com/" with HTTP status 403."
```

From this, IDE is trying to connect to the http server and gets an error.
Try to check "Don't check http connection".